# How to convert image to cvPixelImage in coreml Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, coreml, cvpixelbuffer

I want to convert an image to model image size. I'm getting images using API. here is the code.

```
let model = GoogLeNetPlaces()
var selectImage: BaseModel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let url = URL(string: selectImage.fullURL)
    let imageData = NSData(contentsOf: url!)

    detailImageView.image = UIImage(data: imageData! as Data)

    if let imageToAnalyze = detailImageView.image {

        if let data = sceneLabel(forImage: imageToAnalyze) {
         imageLabel.text = data

        }
    }
}

func sceneLabel(forImage image:UIImage) -> String? {

    if let pixel = ImageProcessor.pixelBuffer(forImage: image.cgImage!){

        guard let scene = try? model.prediction(sceneImage: pixel) else { fatalError("error")}
        return scene.sceneLabel
    }
    return nil
}
```

and, this is the code I am using for image size conversion.

```
struct ImageProcessor {

static func pixelBuffer (forImage image:CGImage) -> CVPixelBuffer? {


    let frameSize = CGSize(width: image.width, height: image.height)

    var pixelBuffer:CVPixelBuffer? = nil
    let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, Int(frameSize.width), Int(frameSize.height), kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA , nil, &pixelBuffer)

    if status != kCVReturnSuccess {
        return nil

    }

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags.init(rawValue: 0))
    let data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!)
    let rgbColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue | CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let context = CGContext(data: data, width: Int(frameSize.width), height: Int(frameSize.height), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer!), space: rgbColorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)


    context?.draw(image, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.width, height: image.height))

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer!, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

    return pixelBuffer

    }
}
```

I'm getting an error for the size.

The image size is not converting to the model image size.

Can anyone help me with this?

This is the error I'm getting

> [coreml] Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=1 "Input image feature sceneImage does not match model description" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Input image feature sceneImage does not match model description, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000006a1d40 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "Image size 3829 x 2411 not in allowed set of image sizes" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Image size 3829 x 2411 not in allowed set of image sizes}}}

Comment: Because of your MLModel's training image size and your image size is difference. You can crop/resize your image to same size with your MLModel's training image size

Comment: can you tell me how do i achieve that?? i'm using GoogleNetPlaces Model. @QuocNguyen

Comment: you can detect it with `VNCoreMLModel` for simple (you don't need to crop/resize image). But if you want to process by PixelBuffer, you can simple crop/resize image to (224x224) image first (GoogleNetPlaces's training image has size 224x224)

Comment: There is some source code for resizing images and turning them into CVPixelBuffers here: https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers

Comment: Thank You @QuocNguyen got it.

Comment: @MatthijsHollemans Thank you